# Unittest is running enitre python file instead of single funciton

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Im writing some unittests for a simple addition program.

```
def add(int1, int2):
a = int1 + int2
return (a)

def run():
    int1 = int(input())
    int2 = int(input())
    ans = add(int1, int2)
    print(ans)
run()
```

But when I run the testing script below on cmd line, it runs the "run()" function and then runs the testing script. I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Any help?

```
import unittest
from simpleaddition import add

class Test_Addition(unittest.TestCase): #first test will check an increase in num digits
    def test_Inc(self):
        ans = add(99, 1)
        self.assertEqual(ans, 100)

    def test_Hard(self): #testing on hard coded/assigned digit
        testDigit = 5555
        testNum = 4444
        testAns = 9999
        ans = add(testDigit, testNum)
        self.assertEqual(ans, testAns)

    def test_Assign(self): #should show that func will only add ints
        num1 = '5555'
        num2 = '4444'
        testAns = 9999
        ans = add(num1, num2)
        self.assertNotEqual(testAns, and)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: If you don't want `run()` being invoked when the `simpleaddition` module is imported, put it in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard

Comment: This worked, thank you @rdas